# Calendar setup doesnt work

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I had been trying for a while to make a "Calendar" that schedule from the current day to the same day next week, but so far everything I tried failed.

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();

switch (day) {
case 1:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    break;
case 2:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
    break;
case 3:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
    break;
case 4:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
    break;
case 5:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    break;
case 6:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
    break;
case 7:
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    break;
}
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

This works for some of the days, for the rest the time is set backwards, or better said,
for exp. taking the today's day 6/4/2014 ->

Jun 2, Mon ...
Jun 3, Tue ...
Jun 4, Wen ...
Jun 5, Thu ...
Jun 6, Fri ...
Jun 7, Saturday ...
Jun 1, Sunday ...

Any ideas how to set proper calendar that sets the time forwards, not backwards?

Comment: take today calendar and add 7 days one at a time to it

Comment: bit more specific please ^

Comment: i don't really understand what you are trying to do, but if your want a schedule from today to next week, take today, then add 1 day to your calendar (that's tomorrow), then add another day (that's the day after) and so on until next wednesday

Comment: If today we are friday, I want to fill the calendar up to the next friday. So I guess ur idea will work here, so thanks bro ^